# Generalization between UML enumeration and class

Tags: uml

Is it correct in accordance with UML specification for UML in version 2.5 to model generalization relationship between UML enumeration and UML class? In page 166 the specification states "As a specification of Classifier, Enumerations can participate in generalization relationships". Is it however correct to put generalization relationship between class and enumeration? If yes, how such a enumeration should than be interpreted?

Comment: You seem to put the cart before the horse. What is the reason for trying to create that generalization? That's more important than making strange constructs and ask about their meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do so. Both elements are `Classifier`s as the UML 2.5 metamodel shows.

[image]

As such you can use inheritance between both.

Now for your question what that would mean. Well, honestly I don't know. Enumerations are basically meant to be just enumerations. In the old days they were just that list of EnumerationLiterals. More recent languages allow for operations/properties as well. But when you pimp them with a Class, then what is the point? Generalization is a blade with two edges. Defining an amphi-car as inheriting from car and ship feels strange. It's neither of both but something new. So in case of Enumeration it's similar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify the issue fully, it means that the oposit direction (generalization the class from the enumeration) is also forbiden. Is it right?

Comment: Thomas, none of the quotations provide any evidence. Enumerations, Datatypes, and Classes are ultimately all Classifiers, which, as you quote, can be related by Generalizations. I just checked the spec and was surprised not to be able to find any limitation. Does one still exist?

Comment: @JimL. Classifier and EncapsulatedClassifier are in fact different metatypes. The way it's presented in the meta-model makes it clear (to me) that a generalization does not make sense. Class composes Classifier.

Comment: @Annabelle Yes. The other way round does also not make sense.

Comment: Yes, a Class can be composed of Classifiers (but it does not have to, think e.g. inner class) and it also is a specialized Classifier. These are two different associations between Classifier and Class, one being a composition and the other a generalization. The latter is missing from the diagram and hence the arguments provided in this answer do not hold.

Comment: @hlg I guess you are right. Both are `Classifier`s. Seems I have to revert my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I still did not find a formal constraint, but you may use the Generalization definition to find evidence whether a generalization between a Class and an Enumeration makes sense (or find examples which have an interpretation):

> A Generalization is a taxonomic relationship between a more general
> Classifier and a more specific Classifier. Each instance of the
> specific Classifier is also an instance of the general Classifier. ([UML 2.5.1, p.138](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF#page=180))

With your construction, an instance of the Enumeration would also be an instance of the Class (or vice versa). Now let's look at what that means.

> When a Classifier is generalized, certain members of its
> generalizations are inherited, that is they behave as though they were
> defined in the inheriting Classifier itself. For example, an inherited
> member that is an attribute may have a value or collection of values
> in any instance of the inheriting Classifier...  ([UML 2.5.1, p.100](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF#page=142))

In fact an Enumeration can have attributes just like any Classifier, thus why shouldn't it inherit those from a Class? Looking further into what it means to be an instance of an Enumeration or an instance of a class, we find this:

> DataTypes model Types whose instances are distinguished only by their
> value. ... Each value of an Enumeration corresponds to one of its
> user-defined EnumerationLiterals. ... EnumerationLiterals may not
> change during their existence, so any attributes on an Enumeration
> shall be read-only. ([UML 2.5.1, p. 209 f.](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF#page=209))

Aha, maybe we could enumerate objects with their attribute values (instances of Class) as values of an Enumeration? Would the instances of the Enumeration than also be instances of the Class? Would that be a suitable interpretation?

I am just thinking out loud, not being sure if this makes much sense. I just wouldn't rule out that there is an interpretation just because I never encountered one or cannot imagine one. In fact, look at Enums in Java - they implicitly extend the Class `java.lang.Enum` and the only reason why they can not extend further user-defined classes or other Enums is that Java does not support multiple inheritance of state ([Oracle Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)).